# The name 'AjaxControlToolkit' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, wcf

This code is written in wcf Service1.svc.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

     [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
   public class enggcollegelist : ICRUD
    {

       public List<string> autobranches(string brname)
       { List<string> lstbranches = new List<string>();
        connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        command = new SqlCommand("select branchname from tblenggbranchnames "+"where branchname LIKE '%'+@branches+'%' ",connection);
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branches",brname);
        resultReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (resultReader.Read())
        {
            string items  =AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(resultReader["branchname"].ToString());

            lstbranches.Add(resultReader["branchname"].ToString());
        }
        connection.Close();
        return lstbranches;

    }
```

In above code "AjaxControlToolkit" is not accepting.
I have downloaded ajax toolkit and installed and also add reference in toolkit.
But same problem exits.

Comment: found solution, just re-added reference of ajax toolkit ,

Comment: string items =AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(resultReader["branchname"].ToString());      get another error for above statement   'no overload for method 'CreateAutoCompleteItem' takes 1 arguments'